# wordpress codex upload file with rename function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to know if there is any other function that can do this.

I was trying to create a function that will upload photo to the wp_handle_upload()

Now what im trying to search is that.
Is it possible that while going to this function the photo will rename.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
$uploadphoto =  $_FILES['image'];
$uploadphoto_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movephoto = wp_handle_upload( $uploadphoto, $uploadphoto_overrides );
```

im trying to do something like this

```
$uploadphoto = '123changename' . $_FILES['image'];
```

I only got errors.
Is there other way?

Comment: It depends on where you are using this code... Take a look at [this search results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=media_handle_sideload).

Answer (score 0):

Use this: 
`$uploadphoto = time() . '_my_file_' . $_FILES['image'];`

where `$_FILES['image']` is an array.
If you want to store the name use:

`$uploadphoto_name = time() . '_my_file_' . $_FILES['image'][0];`